# Make Vim keep the password while editing multiple files remotely

Tags: vim, ssh, remote-access, neovim

Consider you have a workstation, connect this to a remote server and edit some files in it like

```
workstation $ ssh sarah@192.0.0.100     # Log into the remote server
Password: MyPassw0rd!
```

```
server $ ls  /home/sarah/recipes/       # Files you want to edit
applePie.txt    bananaCake.txt
```

```
server $ vi  /home/sarah/recipes/       # Open this directory and edit the files in it
...
:x
```

```
server $ logout                         # Log out and come back to the workstation
```

Now you want to use Vim/Neovim on your own workstation.

```
workstation $ vim scp://sarah@192.0.0.100://home/sarah/recipes/
sarah@192.0.0.100's password: MyPassw0rd!
```

The problem is every time you open files in this server you have to type the same password again.  Is there any way to keep this SSH session alive while Vim/Neovim is editing files in the same remote server?

Comment: Why not use [ssh keys](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+without+password)?

Comment: Because that's tedious if you have multiple new remote servers.  Multiple virtual appliances are created and destroyed automatically, every day, and I regularly access to some of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netrw, which is the tool that handles loading and saving remote files, only prompts for passwords for FTP accounts.  The prompt you're seeing is actually from scp, which, as part of OpenSSH, will only prompt for passwords from a TTY.

Because you're entering your password directly into scp and the scp process that's invoked doesn't live more than ephemerally, there's no way to cache your password.  Even if Netrw did prompt for your password, scp doesn't provide a way to read passwords noninteractively, so Netrw couldn't cache it and pass it on.

You'll need to use SSH keys if you don't want to enter a password every time.  To ease the setup burden, you can use `ssh-copy-id` to copy your keys just one time to the remote system, and then use Vim as normal without a password prompt.